# Pyspark: how to setup initial setting of memory and cores?

Tags: pyspark

I am quite new to `spark` and `pyspark`. I have installed everything I need in a linux machine with `12` cores and `24g` of ram.

When I try to run some command using `pyspark` I noticed that only one processor is running. This is what I am doing in order to initialize the process. Is it ok?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '12')
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.memory", '24g')
spark.conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '24g')
spark.conf.set("spark.python.worker.memory", '24g')
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", '12')
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Comment: spark = SparkSession.builder.config("key","value").getOrCreate() . 
some of the configuration cant be changed after sparksession is created, so use .config before getorcreate

Answer (score 1):

As per config `spark.conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '24g')` , You are giving full RAM to the  single executor so Application Master is not able to launch more executor. Change it to 2g/4g/6g and see the how the executors are added. Please refer below for more information regarding the same.

1. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/
2. https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html